# Close option when other is opened

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have such html code printed with echo :

```
 <input id="58" readonly="readonly" class="cell_to_edit"  value="Accepted">
 <span id="58" class="toggle_status">
    <select class="status_change">
        <option>Accepted</option>
        <option>Waiting</option>
        <option>Canceled</option>
     </select>
  </span>

 <input id="59" readonly="readonly" class="cell_to_edit"  value="Canceled">
 <span id="59" class="toggle_status">
    <select class="status_change">
        <option>Accepted</option>
        <option>Waiting</option>
        <option>Canceled</option>
     </select>
  </span>

Jquery : 

$(function() {
        $('.cell_to_edit').on('click', function () {
                var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
                $(this).hide();
                    $("span[id=" + inputID + "]").show();
                    $("span[id=" + inputID + "]").attr("id",""+inputID+"");
                    $(".status_change").change(function() {
                        var selectIDforAjax = "id="+inputID;
                        console.log(selectIDforAjax);
                        $(this).hide();
                        $("input[id=" + inputID + "]").show();
                    });

            });
        });
```

I have such problem, when I open the selected options and hide input everything is messed up. How to close the option when the second one is opened? Because in future I'll pass the ID to php with Ajax to make the changes in database.

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Comment: In my situation if it will be unique I will show all the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have the id in your case(if the structure of your html is the same as given here). The elements you want to target(`input.cell_to_edit` and `.toggle_status`) are next/prev sibling elements so use that relationship instead of using `ID` to target them.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.cell_to_edit').on('click', function() {
    $(this).hide().next().show();
  });
  $(".status_change").change(function() {
    var $span = $(this).parent();
    $span.hide().prev().show();
    var id = $span.data('id');
    alert(id)
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle_status {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input readonly="readonly" class="cell_to_edit" value="Accepted" />
<span data-id="58" class="toggle_status">
    <select class="status_change">
        <option>Accepted</option>
        <option>Waiting</option>
        <option>Canceled</option>
    </select>
</span>

<input readonly="readonly" class="cell_to_edit" value="Canceled" />
<span data-id="59" class="toggle_status">
    <select class="status_change">
        <option>Accepted</option>
        <option>Waiting</option>
        <option>Canceled</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

Comment: Well actually I need the value of ID , because on select change I will do ajax things.

Comment: then instead of using id use a `data-*` property to store the value like `<span data-id="59" class="toggle_status">...</span>`

Comment: Just googled for data-* usage. Didn't knew that before. Thanks